# How to see the value of a piece of land that is owned by a company or government

Tags: capitalism-lab

In *Capitalism Lab*, the land cost and the Customer Traffic Index is displayed when buying a piece of land that is not owned by a player or government.

[image: Buying an empty plot of land in Capitalism]

From my observations, the higher the Customer Traffic Index, the more valuable the land. How can I know the value or Customer Traffic Index of a piece of land after it has been bought by either a player or a government?

To illustrate the problem, when I hover my mouse cursor over a piece of land owned by the government (beneath an apartment building owned by the government), the value of the land and its Customer Traffic Index are not shown:

[image: Attempting to buy a piece of land owned by the government]

How can I find the value of the land and its Customer Traffic Index?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to find the value of a plot of land beneath a building.

However, for undeveloped plots of land, one can easily find the market value and Customer Traffic Index by hovering the mouse cursor over the small square of land. This method works for both undeveloped land owned by one's own company, and land owned by competitors.

For example:

[image: Value of a plot of land]

The market value of the small square at the top is $2,812,485, and its Customer Traffic Index is 33.